# Storing an image's title text Selenium Webdriver Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, title

I am scraping with python, and I need to save the image title (the text that pops up when you hover over the image). Here is my attempt so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver= webdriver

imageTitle= driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[2]/div/img").title.encode('utf8')
```

When I try to run the code, I get an `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'title'`. I've also tried:

```
imageTitle= driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[2]/div/img").text.encode('utf8')
```

this just changes to an `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'`

I'm sure this is a relatively simple fix, but I am just completely lost on how to do this, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using `find_elements_by_xpath`, not `find_element_by_xpath`, note your one is plural `elements`, while the other one is `element`.

`driver.find_elements_by_xpath` will return a list of elements, `text` is a property for a single element. You need either use `find_element_by_xpath`, or index `find_elements_by_xpath`.

`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'` has clearly told you that.

Furthermore, the title you mean is the attribute of the element, so need this

```
imageTitle= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[2]/div/img").get_attribute("title")
```

[Here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) is the API documentation, please read carefully when coding.

Comment: It appears that you found my error, thanks for the help.